# How to access a variable by its name stored in a string?

Tags: vbscript

In the example bellow I want to write a function that replaces strings  begining with `$` by the actual contents of that variable. Take into account the function will parse all mathing `$somevar` so, don't take it literary being only `param1` and `param2`

```
Dim myCmd, param1, param2 

Const MY_CONST = "constValue"    

param1 = "myParameter1"
param2 = "myParameter2"

myCmd = "myprogram.exe $param1 $param2 $MY_CONST"
myCmd = addParams(myCmd)

Function addParams(cmdStr)

' this function should replace all "$variables" by its respective content
' Example: "myprogram.exe myParameter1 myParameter2 constValue"


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is the equivalent to [Javascript Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It comes to be very useful when composing command lines with arguments and cases where it is necessary to join various strings and variables:

```
Sub ev(ByRef cmdStr)
    Dim rx, matches, match

    ' Replace single quotes with double quotes
    cmdStr = replace(cmdStr, "'", chr(34))

    ' Replace $variavle strings with their actual value
    Set rx = New RegExp
    rx.Global = True
    rx.pattern = "\$\w+"
    Set matches = rx.Execute(cmdStr)
    For each match in matches
        cmdStr = replace(cmdStr, match, eval( replace(match, "$", "") ))
    Next
End Sub


Const HOST = "192.168.0.1"
Dim cmd, param1, param2

param1 = "-t"
param2 = "-w 5000"
cmd = "ping $param1 $param2 $HOST"
ev cmd

wscript.echo cmd
```

A better approach based on Lankymart comment:

```
function bind(cmdStr, arrParams)
    Dim i
    For i = 0 to uBound(arrParams)
        cmdStr = replace(cmdStr, "$"&i+1, arrParams(i))
    Next
    cmdStr = replace(cmdStr, "'", chr(34))
    bind = cmdStr
End Function


cmd = bind("program.exe --param1 '$1' --param2 '$2'", Array(myVar1, myVar2))
```

Comment: The one issue I have with this approach is the use of globally scoped variables, if you are going to build a function for this it should be self-contained. Could you not pass the params in as an `Array()`? Something like `Call ev(cmd, Array(param1, param2))`, that way the `RegExp` would be redundant and the outcome is based on what is passed in the Array.

Comment: Indeed, variables in this approach must be global. Your suggestion is better when working with more complex scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Had to have a little go at making this self-contained, here is my attempt based on [@Azevedo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2935987/azevedo) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43587870/692942).

Couple of additions

- Pass array of parameters in order they appear
- Sending blank parameters in the Array forces removal of associated space.

```vb
Function ev(cmd, params)
  Dim rx, matches, i, result
  result = cmd
  Set rx = New RegExp
  rx.Global = True
  rx.pattern = "\$\w+"
  Set matches = rx.Execute(cmd)
  If matches.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
      If IsArray(params) Then
        If Len(params(i)) > 0 Then params(i) = " " & params(i)
        result = Replace(result, " " & matches(i), params(i))
      End If
    Next
  End If
  ev = result
End Function

Const HOST = "192.168.0.1"
Dim cmd: cmd = "ping $param1 $param2 $HOST"

'Test with all parameters
WScript.Echo ev(cmd, Array("-t", "-w 5000", HOST))
'Test with missing parameter
WScript.Echo ev(cmd, Array("-t", "", HOST))
'Test with no parameters
WScript.Echo ev(cmd, Empty)
```

Output:

```
ping -t -w 5000 192.168.0.1
ping -t 192.168.0.1
ping $param1 $param2 $HOST
```